# Expression Tree not evaluating properly when ExpandoObject used

Tags: linq, lambda, expression-trees, expandoobject

I am writing an expression tree in C# for evaluating equal match and finding whether one of the property on an entity matching with some predefined constant and taking action as per the result. As I am not sure what kind of object will be an input for the expression, I used ExpandoObject and coded expression tree as per that.

When I run the code, I could not get the result as per the condition. Always it resulted false.

```
var dynEmp = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ExpandoObject>("{\"Id\":1,\"Name\":\"Test Name\"}");

ParameterExpression dynpe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "employee");
DynamicExpression dynme = Expression.Dynamic(CreateGetMemberBinder(typeof(object), "Id"), typeof(object), dynpe);

ConstantExpression dynconstant = Expression.Constant(1, typeof(object));

BinaryExpression dynbody = Expression.Equal(dynme, dynconstant);
var dynexpressionTree = Expression.Lambda<Func<dynamic, bool>>(dynbody, new[] { dynpe });
var dynfunc = dynexpressionTree.Compile();
var result = dynfunc(dynEmp);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Update 1:
The CreateGetMemberBinder method is listed below

```
    private static GetMemberBinder CreateGetMemberBinder(Type type, string memberName)
    {
        return (GetMemberBinder)Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.GetMember(
            Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpBinderFlags.None,
            memberName,
            type,
            new CSharpArgumentInfo[] { CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null) }
            );
    }
```

Please correct me the issue on this code.

Many Thanks, Thirumalai M

Comment: What is `CreateGetMemberBinder`?

Comment: Thank for the response. I added CreateGetMemberBinder method as well with the query. Pls validate.

Comment: I believe part of your issue is the `Deserialize` method is creating members of type `JsonElement` and so `Id` is not equal to 1, it is equal to a `JsonElement` of type `Number` with a value of 1.

Comment: Hi NetMage, Thanks for the response. I see below while exploring the deserilized object.

[0] {[Id, ValueKind = Number: "1"]}
[1] {[Name, ValueKind = String: "Test Name"]}

Comment: Is any other way to solve this deserilization issue. I tried Newtonsoft as well.

Comment: When you say "As I am not sure what kind of object will be an input for the expression", what do you mean? You must know the C# type that will be passed in...

Comment: I mean the class to create json string is not predefined. The only constrain is to have the properties on the json that can be used for expression evaluation. For ex: for this example I created JSON from employee class (that has 2 properties, Id and Name), but, later the JSON input may not always from employee class. It can be hand scripted or created from another class that has Id in it (may be student, that has Id property as that is been used for evaluation in this code).